# How to identify text and math fonts from PDF?

Tags: fonts, pdf, mathpazo, eulervm

What are the text and math fonts (most likely) used in [this document](http://math.northwestern.edu/~costello/bcov.pdf)?
At first I thought `\usepackage{mathpazo}`, but the greek letter `\Omega` seems different.

Using pdffonts I get for page 2

```
pdffonts -f 2 -l 2 bcov.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
UGOVRZ+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
ZMKAUH+URWPalladioL-Ital             Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
OZNADR+URWPalladioL-Bold             Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
SOSTRQ+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no      12  0
CBYRKR+EURM10                        Type 1            yes yes no      13  0
CGVYUP+CMSY10                        Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
```

Is it then possible to trace the precise packages used? it seems like a combination of `amsmath` `mathpazo` and `euler`, but not the obvious one.

My QUESTION amounts to: is it possible to use `mathpazo` for everything, except for greek math fonts in `euler`?

Comment: Try using \usepackage`amsmath` and other ams packages as well.

Comment: This is off-topic, so I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)